# MVC ValidateAntiForgeryToken multi-tabs problem

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, antiforgerytoken

We'd been getting "A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid." errors, and on some further investigation, I've managed to recreate the problem in its simplest form - i'm either doing something completely wrong, or this is a limitation of the anti-forgery token system.

Either way, I'd appreciate some advice!

Empty MVC 2 project:
one view page, one controller

view:

```
<%--Sign in form:--%>
<% using(Html.BeginForm("SignIn", "Home", FormMethod.Post)) {%>
    <%= Html.AntiForgeryToken()%>
    <input type="submit" value="Sign in" />
<%}%>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewData["status"] = "Index";
    return View();
}

[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult SignIn()
{
    ViewData["status"] = "Signed In!";
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("username", false);
    return View("Index");
}
```

[EDIT: simplified code example]

In order to recreate the exception, open two non-signed-in tabs - sign-in on the first tab, and then sign-in on the second tab.

The second tab will always throw an anti-forgery exception, when I guess correct behaviour would be to redirect to the signed-in page (sharing the session/authentication of the original signed-in tab)

Any advice would be appreciated!

Cheers,
Dave

Comment: I ended up fixing this problem, by removing the anti-forgery token completely. If you think about it, it doesn't really help at all having it on the sign-in portion of your website anyway - as an attacker would have to know your user-name & password!

Comment: Not entirely true. See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2120/should-i-use-antiforgerytoken-in-all-forms-even-login-and-registration

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The real answer to this problem is simply that you shouldn't use an anti-forgery token on login forms!

It's pointless to "forge" being a user on a *login form* - they aren't logged in!

Comment: Perhaps this answer should be taken with a pinch of salt, when weighed against the answer to this question on AppSec: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2120/when-the-use-of-a-antiforgerytoken-is-not-required-needed It's obscure, and may not be important to everyone, but the should/shouldn't answer isn't straightforward.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the MVC 2 source code it looks like the AntiForgeryToken hidden field includes the User.Identity.Name serialized, if your signed in. In line 69 of the `ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute` it seems to then check your token with the current User.Identity.Name.

```
    string currentUsername = AntiForgeryData.GetUsername(filterContext.HttpContext.User);
    if (!String.Equals(formToken.Username, currentUsername, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
        // error: form token is not valid for this user
        // (don't care about cookie token)
        throw CreateValidationException();
    }
```

Because in your other tab you are now signed in the code above invalidates the existing token which doesn't contain the User.Identity.Name.

This could be fixed by adding a `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(formToken.Username)` around that check but I don't know if that will open up security issues plus it means having a custom MVC 2 Build.

Comment: Yep, this is why it happens for me -- and knowing is half the battle!

Comment: creating a custom build is a security risk. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881157/mvc3-antiforgery-token-multi-tabs/9881484#9881484

Answer (score 0):

You could use the same salt:

```
<% using(Html.BeginForm("SignIn", "Home", FormMethod.Post)) {%>
    <%= Html.AntiForgeryToken("123")%>
    <input type="submit" value="Sign in" />
<%}%>

<% using(Html.BeginForm("Protected", "Home", FormMethod.Post)) {%>
    <%= Html.AntiForgeryToken("456")%>
    <input type="submit" value="Do secret stuff" />
<%}%>
```

And in your controller:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken(Salt = "123")]
public ActionResult SignIn()
{
    ViewData["status"] = "Signed In!";
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("username", false);
    return View("Index");
}

[Authorize]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken(Salt = "456")]
public ActionResult Protected()
{
    ViewData["status"] = "Authed";
    return View("Index");
}
```

Do the same with the other token but make sure to pick a **different** salt.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - but that doesn't solve the problem, cheers, Dave.

Comment: It solved it for me. Make sure you use the same salt in the controller and the view for the signin form and action and a different salt for the protected action and view. Also don't forget to recompile and close the browser window to clear any stale cookies.

Comment: Make sure you close your browser to start a new session - You actually don't need the 2nd form/controller action at all in order to recreate this issue.

Comment: In your original question you talked about different browser tabs. If I close the browser and start a new there's no problem at all.

Comment: No - I mean, open a fresh browser - then open two tabs.
Sign-in on tab 1, then tab 2 will always fail with the exception.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I did. Adding the salt solved the problem.

Comment: This def' doesn't work. I'm happy to send you the code, if you want (thanks for your help)! :)

Comment: OK, I see. Try redirecting in the POST action instead of returning a view: `return RedirectToAction("Index")`.